# Android SimpleFramework Namespace prefix

Tags: android, namespaces, xml-parsing, simple-framework

on Android I'm using SimpleFramework to parse incoming XML and create appropriate objects (which are saved to DB afterwards...)

A part of XML looks like this:

```
<CheckId xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">  
   <a:guid>00300001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:guid>
</CheckId>
```

Where `<a:guid>` can repeat 1..N

My element annotations look like this:

```
@ElementList(required = false, name="CheckId")  
@Namespace(reference="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, orderColumnName = "Guid", columnName = TABLE_CHECK_ID_LIST_COLUMN)
public Collection<TableCheck> TableCheckIdList;
```

and in the TableCheck class is:

```
@Root(name = "CheckId")
@Order(elements = { "guid" })   
public static class TableCheck implements XMLParseable {

@Element(required = false, name="guid")
@DatabaseField
public String Guid;
...
}
```

After parsing is done, the Collection contains as many items as tag `<a:guid>` appeared in the XML. However, the property Guid is always NULL.

I've tried to play with Namespace / Prefix attributes but the result is always the same - NULL value in Guid property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the @Namespace annotation. Here Guid is null because of one of the following reasons.

a) It is written like <a:guid/>

b) It is written line <a:guid></a:guid>

c) Something is setting it to be null after you have finished parsing it.

Try using constructor injection and set the value as final, then you know nothing else is setting it to null after the object is created.

Comment: The element look like this:
<a:guid>00300001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:guid>

However, it's still always null, I made sure that there is nothing rewriting the value after the parsing is finished. I even went debugging how the SimpleFramework do the parsing, it recognizes automatically the namespace, prefix and guid element but it puts null to the value of the element. Dunno why :(